# How to access the tr inner table tr

Tags: jquery

I am having the below table structure

```
<table class="table-striped table-bordered" style="width: 50%; text-indent: 5px" id="table1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th style="text-align: center; background-color: gray; color: white;" rowSpan="1" colspan="3">HELLO</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>#</th>
      <th colspan="1">Name</th>
      <th style="text-align: right;">Roll</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody ng-repeat="x in x.data.nameList">
    <tr>
      <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
      <td colspan="1">{{x.name}}</td>
      <td style="text-align: right;">{{x.position | number:2}}
        <a class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down" ng-click=toggle($index) data-toggle="toggle"></a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id=name{{$index}} class="collapse">
      <td colspan="1"></td>
      <td colspan="2" style="align-content: right;">
        <table class="table table-condensed table-striped" style="width: 100%; text-indent: 5px" ;>

          <tr>
            <th style="width: 15%; text-align: right;">#</th>
            <th nowrap style="width: 20%; text-align: right;">name</th>
            <th nowrap style="width: 30%; text-align: right;">class</th>
            <th nowrap style="width: 35%; text-align: right;">Position</th>
          </tr>
          <tr style="text-align: right;" ng-repeat="b in x.positionList">
            <td>{{$index+1}}</td>
            <td>{{b.idBook}}</td>
            <td>{{b.bookName}}</td>
            <td>{{b.position | number:2}}</td>
          </tr>

        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

</table>
```

I want to access the inner table tr using the jquery as below,

```
$("#table1>tbody tr:eq(3)").each(function() {
```

But each time its returning me only single record of the inner table TR.I am expecting that it will iterate and will return all the record/row of the inner table TR.
Could you please suggest me any approach ,how can i do this.

Answer (score 3):

use without eq operator to get all tr elements under #table1.

```
$("#table1>tbody tr").each(function()
```

to get inner table's tr elements use:

```
$("#table1>tbody tr>td>table tr").each(function()
```

Answer (score 0):

just use this code:

```
$('table table').on('click',function(){
    alert('1');
});
```

don't forget vote up :)

Comment: what will get returned by this.all the TR/TD

Comment: that is just selector. after that you can handle it as you want